# How can I change the items order in a pulldown list of filter in views?

Tags: views

Hello Drupal community.

I have a question about Views.
I have a “People” view with a role filter and the pulldown list for this filter look like this:

- Administrator
- Editor
- Approver

I would like to know if it is possible to change the order of items in the pulldown list to make it look, for example, like this:

- Administrator
- Approver
- Editor

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could probably change the roles order in People>Permissions>Roles (simple drag and drop) and the Views filter will use it by default.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. It turned out to be more simple than I thought.